# How to check if type is explicitly/implicitly constructible?

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++17, type-traits, explicit

How can it be checked that some type is explicitly (or vice versa implicitly) constructible from other type? Is it any SFINAE trick in this situation?

I can write `is_explicitly_constructible` as a [combination of `std::is_constructible` and `std::is_convertible`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8ac53980c5ed0e3):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Type, typename Argument>
struct is_explicitly_constructible
    : std::bool_constant
        <
            std::is_constructible<Type, Argument>::value &&
            !std::is_convertible<Argument, Type>::value
        >
{
};
```

But do I take into account all possible cases in such code?

Comment: It seems to me that combining `declval` with `static_cast` should determine whether one type is convertible from another type. Combine that with a typical SFINAE test, and that should do the trick.

Comment: Is the question just: is this correct? If so, yes it is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But I want to check if one type _constructible_ from another type, not _convertible_. And `static_cast` supports convertion of types that are not classes themselves.

Comment: @Barry And no pitfalls here? Like competing constructors or something else...

Comment: @Constructor `std::is_constructible<X,Y>` does the right thing. It doesn't check if literally the constructor `X(Y )` exists - just checks if a hypothetical `X x(y);` would be well-formed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. A type `T` is explicitly constructible from an argument `A` if

1. It is constructible at all from `A`. That is, a hypothetical `T x(a)` is valid.
2. Implicit conversions are ill-formed. That is, the hypothetical function `T test() { return a; }` would be ill-formed.

`std::is_constructible` tests #1, and `std::is_convertible` tests the validity of #2. Hence, wanting #1 and not #2 would be `is_explicitly_constructible` just as #1 and #2 would be `is_implicitly_constructible`.

---

Such an `is_explicitly_constructible`/`is_implicitly_constructible` pair is how you would implement a constructor being conditionally `explicit`. For instance, in libstdc++, these two constructors for `optional` exist:

[implicit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/optional#L523):

```
 template <typename _Up = _Tp,
            enable_if_t<__and_<
              __not_<is_same<optional<_Tp>, decay_t<_Up>>>,
              is_constructible<_Tp, _Up&&>,   // (*) 
              is_convertible<_Up&&, _Tp>      // (*)
              >::value, bool> = true>
  constexpr optional(_Up&& __t)
```

[explicit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/optional#L532):

```
  template <typename _Up = _Tp,
            enable_if_t<__and_<
              __not_<is_same<optional<_Tp>, decay_t<_Up>>>,
              is_constructible<_Tp, _Up&&>,        // (*)
              __not_<is_convertible<_Up&&, _Tp>>   // (*)
              >::value, bool> = false>
  explicit constexpr optional(_Up&& __t);
```

You can see that libstdc++ uses the same expressions that you do.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer! What about `is_explicitly_convertible`/`is_implicitly_convertible`?

Comment: @Constructor Huh?

Comment: `is_implictly_convertible == is_convertible && !is_explicitly_convertible`, `is_explicitly_convertible == ?`

Comment: There is no implicitly vs explicitly convertible. There is convertible, which implies implicit.

Comment: Conversions using `static_cast` are explicit, but they involve some conversions, that can not be implicit.

Comment: @Constructor I guess what you're looking for is that `is_explicitly_convertible<From,To>` is `std::is_constructible<To,From>` and `is_implicitly_convertible<From,To>` is `std::is_convertible<From,To>`.